# ggplot() color each point manually

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I create a scatter-plot in ggplot() with each points coloured manually? The necessary colours are given in my dataframe.

```
> head(df)
     x    y       col
1 0.72 2757   #2AAE89
2 0.72 2757   #2DFE83
3 0.72 2757   #40FE89
4 0.70 2757   #28FE97
5 0.86 2757   #007C7D
6 0.75 2757   #24FEA1
```

The colour of the points must be exactly as given in the dataframe

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Comment: There's nothing I can do about the duplicated post - consider checking the linked answers. You cannot change your question once it is answered - that's how the site works. It wastes the efforts of the answerers

Comment: @YvetteColomb, checked already, no relevant answers exist.

Comment: then you need to reword your question. There's a limit to what I can do to help you in the comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily there is a relatively easy solution by using `scale_colour_identity()`, see the following example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

z <- "     x    y    z     col
1 0.72 2757   86 #2AAE89
2 0.72 2757   86 #2DFE83
3 0.72 2757   86 #40FE89
4 0.70 2757   82 #28FE97
5 0.86 2757   26 #007C7D
6 0.75 2757   79 #24FEA1"

df <- read.table(text = z, header = T)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = col)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

EDIT: I made a mistake in loading in the data, but the plotting syntax is still valid.